# JQuery scroll event not functioning properly

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, web-frontend

I am creating a mobile website, on one of the web pages I have created a dashboard with three scroll-able pages on. In the bottom right corner of each page is a button to press, upon pressing this button a JQuery event is fired and should scroll to the next page. Or back to the top if you are at the bottom. However the button on page 2 does not trigger the scroll event, but the button on page 1 and 3 do.

Here is the JQuery event;

```
if ($(".button-container").click(function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('html, body, scroll-container').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#" + "page" + id).offset().top
            });
        }));
```

The JQuery find the id of the button press and creates a string to find the id of the page to scroll to.

Here is the HTML code:

```
    <div class="scroll-page" id="page1">
        <div class="field">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar-o fa-stack-3x"></i>
                <i class="fa-stack-1x calendar-text">21</i>
                <i class="fa-stack-2x month-text">MAR</i>
            </span>
            <span><a href="#" class="button button21"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> View latest payslip</a></span>
        </div>
        <div class="button-container" id="2">
            <a class="scroll-button" href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="scroll-page" id="page2">
        <div class="button-container" id="3">
            <a class="scroll-button" href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="scroll-page" id="page3">
        <div class="button-container" id="1">
            <a class="scroll-button" href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

</scroll-container>
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any obvious mistake, did you try to log the offset() value to the console to see if it's getting the right one? Also, you're calling `event.preventDefault()` without passing 'event' to the function, so that should actually throw an exception. You should replace your event handler with this:

```
$(".button-container").click(function (event) {
```